# Will Airflow load the new code when calling Clear

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm developing and testing an Airflow DAG, the version of airflow is less than 2.

Let's say my DAG has this structure:
`A -> B`

`A` takes 1 hour to complete but works fine.

`B` contains errors in the code and I need to fix them.

I know that with `Clear` I can re-run `B`
, what I wanted to know is what happens if before `Clear`-ing I replace the code of `B` with a newer one containing the fixes of the errors. Will the operation of clearing also load the new code and make airflow work with it or it will airflow still use the old code containing the errors?

**In the latter case, is there a way to run and test all the new versions of `B` containing the fixes without having to re-run `A` which takes a long time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Airflow load the new code when calling Clear

No.

DAG parsing is a separated process which runs independently. This process parse the `.py` file which contains DAG into the metastore database. This happens every 30 seconds (default of [min_file_process_interval](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval)). The Airlfow services (Scheduler / Webserver / etc) see only the code that is stored in the metastore. These components have no way of knowing if code is up to date or not - they simply execute the stored version of it. This is a design choice of decoupling the services from the `.py` files. You can read more about DAG file processing [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dagfile-processing.html).

Airlfow indicates the last timestamp specific DAG was parsed in the UI:

Simply clear the task after the new version was parsed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great reply, I just have one question to clear things up. So, the new code is not automatically parsed on clear, but it is parsed every X seconds? So if I push the new code, wait for the parsing interval and then clear the task, the new task *will* run the newer code?

Comment: Exactly. You can also control over how often parsing happens.

Comment: What if the min_file_process_interval is set to 0? Is it going to look for the new files in a never ending loop?

Comment: Im not sure if this will work. Note that lowering the value will increase the CPU usage. I would suggest to keep an eye on monitoring the machine stats when you modify the value.

Comment: yeah, exactly my doubts. I'm not managing the Airflow I'm using and when asking for the value of that interval I've been told it's 0